# Image in button doesn't load, i only get a blue square

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to add a button to a screen and edit it programmatically, but most of the edits don't respond.

This is the button code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonTest: UIButton!

let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

let buttonImg = ResizeImage(UIImage(named: "Blokker")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    buttonTest.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screen.height - 300, width: screen.width * 0.5, height: screen.width * 0.5)
    buttonTest.setImage(buttonImg, forState: .Normal)
    buttonTest.setTitle("Test", forState: .Normal)
    buttonTest.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(buttonTest)
```

The ResizeImage function works, i've used it in other view controllers already. The code for this is quoted below. The buttonTest.frame method doesn't work, the button will always stay in the same place without edits to the size. The image doesn't load either, in the place where the image should be, I can only see a blue square.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

The ResizeImage func:

```
func ResizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * heightRatio, size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * widthRatio,  size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: try buttonTest.imageView?.imageRenderingMode = .AlwaysOriginal

Comment: That didn't work directly, but i used it in this way: `let buttonImg = ResizeImage(UIImage(named: "Blokker")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)`

Comment: Any idea on the frame problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question I already answered in comment

Use `imageView.imageRenderingMode = .AlwaysOriginal` if you want the image to be the same as the source

and `imageView.imageRenderingMode = .AlwaysTemplate` if you want the image to be the same color as its container (images with no alpha channel will be a colored square)

For the frame problem, why are you the following line? Remove it.

```
view.addSubview(buttonTest)
```

Buttontest already has a superview as it's an outlet from storyboard/xib. Also, do not change frame rect if you're designing the button using storyboard/xib. You should learn how to use constraints for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using FruitAddict's comment:

```
let buttonImg = ResizeImage(UIImage(named: "Blokker")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

solved the image problem, for people who experience the same problem!

The frame problem hasn't changed so far..

Answer (score 0):

according to me please use SDWebImage ThirdParty library please follow below link:-

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

or you can also install through pod also and use this library....

i show you below code using swift language:-

```
 let imageurl: NSURL? =  NSURL(string: "")

  imageview1.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage:UIImage(named:"Ahmedabad_BRTS.jpg"))
```